# Why this code is showing higher native memory consumption

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, performance-monitor

I have created a simple test application as follows.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PerfMonTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static List<byte[]> byteArray = new List<byte[]>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start now");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Program.ProcessData(); });

            
            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { t1});
            Console.WriteLine("done ...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static byte[] GetData()
        {
            return new byte[1024 * 1024 * 50];
        }

        public static void ProcessData()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
            {
                byteArray.Add(GetData());
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                Console.WriteLine("GC Memory consumed:" + Convert.ToString((GC.GetTotalMemory(false) / (1024 * 1024))) + " MB");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While this application is running, I am also capturing the two counters `Private Bytes` and `# Bytes in all heaps`. Its result looks as follows.

[image]

According to this [article](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2008/07/13/is-it-a-managed-or-a-native-memory-leak/), the graph should have looked like following.
[image]

My question is why private bytes are going up even though when # of bytes in all heaps are barely increasing? Or my code can cause any native leak that is showing up in `Private bytes` counter?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're using an incredibly contrived test, which doesn't match real world scenarios.

You're allocating `new byte[...]` but it's never going out of scope and therefore it's not getting collected by the Garbage Collector. That's why you're getting a steadily increasing line for `private bytes`.

Similarly, `byteArray` is being allocated on the heap and is not going out of scope. It's needing to allocate more space as it grows, but it grows in chunks, which is why you get those steps in the `bytes in all heaps`.

If you were to periodically delete entries from the list, you'd see that the `private bytes` would cycle in much the same way as the graph from the article would show, though the list itself (and therefore the heap) would never shrink in allocated bytes.